# Teradata excel importing blank columns

Tags: excel, teradata

I created a table and made Rep_Region VARCHAR(50),Region VARCHAR(50). In Regions, I have the word NA for North America. However, once I import my excel sheet into the table teradata is spitting out blanks for the columns that are supposed to have NA. Is there a way to resolve this without changing the name of NA in my excel file?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) You have tagged both MySQL and Teradata, those are two separate products. 2) You don't share how you are importing your excel file into Teradata. What product are you using, how are you using it? 3) With whatever tool that is, is it your belief that the "NA" value is being ignored on import as if it were a "#N/A" error?

Comment: Did you quote around NA?